# devtools::check(document = FALSE): Required Fields missing or empty

Tags: r, r-package

1. Create a directory named "minimal".
2. Create a directory named "minimal/R".
3. Create a file named DESCRIPTION in the minimal directory and the contents:

```
Package: minimal
Type: Package
Title: add two numbers
Version: 1.0
Date: 2022-11-08
Author@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@acme.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: takes two arguments and returns sum
License: GNU GPL
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.2.1
```

4. Create a file `add.R` in the directory `minimal/R` with the following contents:

```
#' add two numbers
#'
#' @param x first number
#' @param y second number
#'
#' @return sum of x and y
#' @export
add <- function(x, y)
    x + y
```

5. Open an R session within `minimal` and enter the command `devtools::check()`

Among some lines of output, I receive the following error message:

```
* checking for file 'minimal/DESCRIPTION' ... ERROR
Required fields missing or empty:
  'Author' 'Maintainer'
* DONE
```

6. Add the following lines to DESCRIPTION:

```
Author: First Last <first.last@institution.com>
Maintainer: First Last <first.last@institution.com>
```

The error message does not appear any more.

I wonder if I am doing it right, as "R Packages" by Hadley Wickham, in its current PDF form, explicitly discourages using the "Author" and "Maintainer" fields

Comment: Well, just use `Authors@R` instead.

Comment: Are you using `Authors@R`?

Comment: Yes I am. If I use ```Authors@R``` instead, the error message above is issued.

Comment: @ipofanes In that case you need to post a [mcve] because I cannot reproduce this: there is no such message with a correct `Authors@R` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this, I added a short instruction for a minimal example, hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, its a simple typo! You wrote `Author@R`, not `Authors@R`.

Comment: Cheers, that was indeed the issue with my original script.